# is Zen nineSixty theme compactible with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, drupal, drupal-6, 960.gs

I have created a custom theme using Zen nineSixty (960 Grid system) in drupal and it works and looks great on all major browsers. I was just wondering if anyone could let me know if I need to do anything else to get this theme working on iPhone or is it auto compatible. Many of our potential clients use iPhone so was wanted to check in if Zen nineSixty (960 Grid system) is iPhone compatible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything special to things to work on the iPhone. iPhones can render all normal webpages it does use webkit after all. The 960 grid system wont be a problem either.

If you want to make it really slick, you will have to make a mobile version though. But then you can make your site look like a native application.